# Having trouble centering the last two images, and the first image is overblown

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, positioning

I am learning HTML and CSS and I am trying to replicate Apple website as my first real project. I am having trouble with the images, the first image is overblown out of proportion, it is way too big than it actually is. The other two images proportions are fine, however, they are pushed to the right of the screen even though I have the parents div width set to 100%, and these child elements set accordingly to the page. Please have a look and tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <title>Apple</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./apple2.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<div id="wrapper">

<body>
<nav> <!--Main navigation of the site-->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPad</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TV</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="content">
    <div class="airpodspro"> <!--div class 1 of main content-->
        <h1>Airpods Pro</h1>
        <h4>Magic like you've never heard</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Learn more ></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Buy ></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="iphone11pro"> <!--div class 2 of main content-->
        <h1>iPhone 11 Pro</h1>
        <h4>Pro cameras. Pro display. Pro performance</h4>
        <h6>From $24.95/mo. or $599 with trade-in.</h6>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Learn more ></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Buy ></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="iphone11"> <!--div class 3 of main content-->
        <h1>iPhone 11</h1>
        <h4>Just the right amount of everything</h4>
        <h6>From $16.62/mo. or $399 with trade-in.</h6>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Learn more ></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Buy ></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
</body>

</div>

.html {
    font-size: 22px;
}

body {
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

html body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;

}

#wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

nav {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    word-spacing: 4em;
    padding: 0.04%;
    width: 100%;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

li{
    display: inline;
    color: white;
 }

nav ul {
    text-align: center;
}

nav a {
    color: white;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}


.airpodspro {
    background-color: #5aa8cc;
    height: 800px;
    background-image: url("https://www.apple.com/v/home/ep/images/heroes/airpods-pro- 
    takeover/airpods_pro__fok8ao5xkga6_large.jpg");
}


 .iphone11pro {
    background-color: #6fffd4;
    margin-top: 53%;
    background-image: url("https://www.apple.com/v/home/ep/images/heroes/iphone-11- 
    pro/hero__dvsxv8smkkgi_large.jpg");
 }

.iphone11 {
    background-color: #dc84ff;
    margin-top: 89%;
    background-image: url("https://www.apple.com/v/home/ep/images/heroes/iphone- 
    11/hero__dvsxv8smkkgi_large.jpg");

}

.airpodspro, .iphone11pro {
    color: #ececec;
}

.iphone11pro, .iphone11 {
    height: 500px;
}

.airpodspro, .iphone11pro, .iphone11 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5% 40%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Maybe some help here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Answer (score 1):

You are using image in CSS As background image properties.
Its better download the respective image from apple website and then use them
in img tag in your HTML. This way you will have better control over image.

Also when you are using the image the way you are already using because of the apple link, its also downloading js codes and controlling the behavior of website. So check out for it.
Thanks, me later.